# Is there any efficient way to reuse Tikz paths, memory-wise?

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are plenty of questions here regarding reusing paths definitions: the answers mostly revolve around macro definition. This is **not** what I am looking for: macros are wasteful; each time it is called, a new object is created and stored in the PDF file.

What I want is basically some way to store a given Tikz element as a *unique* object in the PDF file. That unique object would then be referred multiple times in the document.

I had great hope for `\savebox` but it seems that it is only useful to save on compilation time (file size increases with each use of the box).

From what I understood, `pic` exhibits the same problem.

So is there any way to define an object only once and reuse it again and again?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  Do you have a reference for "macros are wasteful; each time it is called, a new object is created and stored in the PDF file"? Its not something I was aware of, so would like to know more.

Comment: As far as I know, TeX macros are just that, macros. There are expended to whatever they are suppose to embody. So unless Tikz contains some clever code to prove that two different calls to the same macro are in fact identical, it's just going to regenerate everything all over again. In practice, the size of the file increases with the number of calls to the "offending" macro (provided that everything else is equal, number of pages, number of characters, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, even PDF specification does not allow this other than *XObjects* file stream. Otherwise all vector image components are PDF graphics objects. And these objects are dumped by TikZ as `\pdfliteral`s. The only case where TikZ keeps graphical objects ready, is the objects that are *protocolled* such as arrow heads and a few others. But even then from the PDF point of view they are genuine objects.

Besides PGF tries to be platform independent. This will not work with other formats hence won't be, I'm almost sure, implemented.